# Replacing string mismatches with identical and correct names

Tags: r, string

The issue I am currently dealing with is list of species received from different sources. I copied a small fraction of the original list here to address the issue. The first column contains the names of species and the names from the same species are not identical, as was already mentioned they are coming from different sources. For example, in the first three rows the correct name would be the one corresponding to position `C2` (`Arabidopsis.thaliana`). And the names corresponding to positions `C1` and `C3` should be corrected accordingly. Likewise, the next correct name is the one corresponding to `D1`, `F3`, and `G1` and other names within the same species must be corrected according to the correct name.
Thanks in advance for your advise.
Part of my data:

```
dat<-structure(list(Species=c("A. thaliana","Arabidopsis.thaliana","ARABIDOPSIS Thaliana","Pisum.sativum","P. Sativum","PISUM SATIVUM","B. Vulgaris"
                    ,"BETA VULGARIS","Beta.vulgaris","Secale.cereale","S. CEREALE","SECALE CEREALE")
                    ,Position=c("C1","C2","C3","D1","D2","D3","F1","F2","F3","G1","G2","G3")
                      ))

dat<-data.frame(dat)

dat
                Species Position
1           A. thaliana       C1
2  Arabidopsis.thaliana       C2
3  ARABIDOPSIS Thaliana       C3
4         Pisum.sativum       D1
5            P. Sativum       D2
6         PISUM SATIVUM       D3
7           B. Vulgaris       F1
8         BETA VULGARIS       F2
9         Beta.vulgaris       F3
10       Secale.cereale       G1
11           S. CEREALE       G2
12       SECALE CEREALE       G3
```

Comment: What is the logic for identifying the "correct name"?

Comment: Basically the species name should be followed based on Species Taxonomy Nomenclature. Here, I mean the full name of the genus starting with Capital letter followed by (.) and the subspecies with lowercase letters. I hope I could clarify.

Comment: I would use chatgpt or any other LLM ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could help:

```
  pacman::p_load(dplyr, stringr, tidyr)
  dat %>% 
    mutate(Species2 = str_extract(Species, pattern = "(^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+$)", group = 1),
           P = str_extract(Species, pattern ="\\D")) %>% 
    group_by(P) %>% 
    fill(Species2, .direction="downup") %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-P)
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   Species              Position Species2            
   <chr>                <chr>    <chr>               
 1 A. thaliana          C1       Arabidopsis.thaliana
 2 Arabidopsis.thaliana C2       Arabidopsis.thaliana
 3 ARABIDOPSIS Thaliana C3       Arabidopsis.thaliana
 4 Pisum.sativum        D1       Pisum.sativum       
 5 P. Sativum           D2       Pisum.sativum       
 6 PISUM SATIVUM        D3       Pisum.sativum       
 7 B. Vulgaris          F1       Beta.vulgaris       
 8 BETA VULGARIS        F2       Beta.vulgaris       
 9 Beta.vulgaris        F3       Beta.vulgaris       
10 Secale.cereale       G1       Secale.cereale      
11 S. CEREALE           G2       Secale.cereale      
12 SECALE CEREALE       G3       Secale.cereale
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, just a question what would be the pattern for creating variable P if there are both capital and lowercase letter for the first letter within each species?

Comment: @SAL provide a simple example for me to understand and update the answer.

Comment: For example, if for the first species, one of the strings start with small letter (e.g, arabidopsis. thaliana) and others with capital letter as what I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1):

No sure whether this works to 100% correct, but you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Species = c("A. thaliana", "Arabidopsis.thaliana", "ARABIDOPSIS Thaliana"))



df %>% 
  mutate(First = str_sub(Species, 1, 1) %>% toupper(), 
         Second = str_split(Species, " |[.]") %>% map_chr(tail, 1) %>% tolower()) %>% 
  unite(SpeciesID, First, Second)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species              SpeciesID 
  <chr>                <chr>     
1 A. thaliana          A_thaliana
2 Arabidopsis.thaliana A_thaliana
3 ARABIDOPSIS Thaliana A_Thaliana
```